# Is it possible to install Windows IoT to a USB drive and use this to boot?

Tags: pi-3, usb, windows-iot

I can't find anything online about installing Windows IoT to an USB drive. My Raspberry Pi 3's microSD slot is occupied, and the official guide says I need to use a microSD card in order to flash it with Windows IoT. I want to flash a USB drive with windows 10 IoT and have my Raspberry Pi 3 boot from that instead of the microSD card.

I have thought of two ways I could do this:

1. Set up my Pi 3 to boot from USB, copy the Linux image to a USB flash drive and boot it.
2. Follow the Windows IoT setup, even though it's for SD cards.
3. Hope Windows IoT installer won't complain that it's not an SD card.

The other way I thought of was

1. Set up my Pi 3 to boot from USB, copy the Linux image to a USB microSD card reader with a microSD card inserted.
2. Follow the Windows IoT setup
3. Hope Windows IoT installer won't complain I'm using an USB card reader.

Is this possible or has anyone attempted anything like this?

Comment: Turns out this is not possible. After setting the Pi to boot from USB and verifying this works with a Raspbian Jesse image flashed to a drive, I reflashed the drive with Windows IoT. I was greeted with a black screen and no green software light.